# Validate "Runtime JSON array" with "Validation Rules"

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-validate

We know that there are several plugins to perform validations using jQuery, on HTML forms.

We are using jQuery Datatables, using inline editing using DataTables Editor.

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/api/clientValidation.html

The issue is each time a row is submitted, with several fields in each row being editable, we really don't want to keep writing "if-else" conditions to validate all possible editable columns.

When user edits cell, what we get is a JSON name-value array (current Row data), for example in this format,

```
var rowData = { 
              fld_name1: "value1",
              fld_name2: "value2",
              fld_name3: "value3"
              fld_name4: "value4"
              fld_name5: "value5"
           }
```

Wanted to check if we can feed this array to any validations rules array for e.g format used by jQuery Validation Plugin, https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

```
rules: {
            fld_name1: "required",
            fld_name2: "required",
            fld_name3: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            fld_name4: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },

            fld_name5: "required"
        },
```

And check if current "rowData" validates good with rules defined in "rules" array.

Here "rowData" array is dynamic array, created 1 separate instance for each Row in Datatable.

Also HTML FORM Element (Text Field) is generated dynamically by jQuery Datatables Editor. So don't have option to setup form type init on jQuery Validation Plugin.

I am good with using any jQuery validation available that can provide this runtime array validation functionality.

Comment: JQuery Datatables Editor generates Input Form Fields and related information dynamically on the fly. There is no wrapping form as such on which we can call .validate(). Even if try to do this, it will have other interference with existing Datatables Editors logic/listeners.

Simple solution to match JSON array (ROW Data) with Validations Rules. Was checking for solution in this lines, which can match rules from "rowData" with "rules", and output any Validations Messages for rules which don't match or have error with data in "rowData".

Comment: The question was asking for solution for matching "rowData" (Dynamic JSON Named Array) with "rules" (Predefined Validations Rules).

Not sure why the question was downgraded. I am trying to find a solution to a real problem ("Comparing JSON Named Arrays" to "Validation Rules") without reinventing the wheel for all the validation rules. JQuery Validation Plugin seems to have done all the research for different validations combinations. Exposing the functionality to compare not just forms, but to Dynamic JSON (Key:Value Pair) Arrays would make it even more dynamic and useful utility plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, for people who are looking for solution for runtime JSON named array validation, Following library solved this issue,  https://validatejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

> When user edits cell, what we get is a JSON name-value array (current Row data), for example in this format ....  Wanted to check if we can feed this array to any validations rules array for e.g format used by JQuery Validation Plugin

You cannot "dynamically" feed anything into the `rules` object.  Since `.validate()` is called ***once*** on page load to initialize the plugin, it cannot be called again... it's ignored.

> Also HTML FORM Element (Text Field) is generated dynamically by jQuery Datatables Editor. So don't have option to setup form type init on jQuery Validation plugin.

Although you cannot init the dynamic fields using `.validate()`, the developer provides a method called [`.rules()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) that you can call to dynamically assign, update or remove rules from any form input element *at any time*.  So you'll have to parse your JSON array and apply `.rules()` as you see fit...

```
$('[name="fld_name1"]').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ejc1dq8g/**

You can apply to multiple fields at once, as long as you attach the selector to an `.each()`.

```
$('[name^="fld_"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
    });
});
```

---

*Alternatively*, you can simply use [HTML5 validation attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) on any form input element and the jQuery Validate plugin will pickup and use these automatically, even on dynamically created elements.

```
<input name="fld_name1" required="required" minlength="2" ....
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/84zv61n4/**

---

**EDIT**:

Quoting [OP's Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37124039/validate-runtime-json-array-with-validation-rules/37125376?noredirect=1#comment61924543_37124039):

> "There is no wrapping `form` as such on which we can call `.validate()`"

If that's the case, you absolutely cannot use the jQuery Validate plugin without a `<form></form>` container.  There is no workaround.  I wish you would have mentioned this critical detail in the OP as it would have saved time & effort.

Comment: We really don't override Datatable Editors logic/listeners and leave it Editor on form elements generation and submit.

The place where we want to apply these validation rules is before making Ajax request to server, in Editors function where we get access to Table data in JSON names/value array pair . So here we are trying to validate name array to validation rules.

Second approach of using HTML5 validation attributes will require extending Datatable editors functions for different fields.